# How do I chain route controllers together in Express 4.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, I'm using express.  I'd like to chain controllers together using next().

I've got three.  They do different things and I'd like to mix and match them together.  checkEmailVerification goes to a fail page if bad, or next() if good.  The other two just next().  completeE() would wrap it all up.

```
app.core.users.checkEmailVerification,
app.core.users.processVerification,
app.mean.subscribeMarketingEmails,
app.core.users.completeEmailVerification
```

My first thought was to express this as:

```
// Confirm users email
app.route('/auth/confirm/:confirmationCode').get(
    function(req, res, next) {
        app.core.stack(req, res, next, [
            app.core.users.checkEmailVerification,
            app.core.users.processVerification,
            app.mean.subscribeMarketingEmails
        ]);
    }
);
```

So, I wrote the function below as a programming challenge for myself.

It doesn't work.  C'est la vi.  So my two questions are:

1. What's the best way to do this?  There is probably something already made for this.
   *Edit:* Maybe this is it.
   // Confirm users email
   app.route('/auth/confirm/:confirmationCode').get(app.core.users.checkEmailVerification);
   app.route('/auth/confirm/:confirmationCode').get(app.core.users.processVerification);
   app.route('/auth/confirm/:confirmationCode').get(app.mean.subscribeMarketingEmails);
2. Can you see what I missed in the code?  The recursion isn't updating 'current'. The output is below:

Thanks!

```
  // FIXME: this needs work
  /**
   *  Stack req controllers through the use of next()
   *
   *  E.g.  app.core.stack(req, res, [ 
              first, 
              second, 
              third
            ])
   *
   *  == more or less ==>
   *
   *  first(req, res, second(req, res, third(req, res)))
   */
  core.stack = function(req, res, next, controllers, current) {

    // current defaults to 0;
    current = current || 0;

    console.log('--> Current in stack:'+current);

    // Check if something went wrong.
    if (current < 0 || current >= controllers.length)
      throw "core.stack() parameter current is invalid";

    // If this is the last controller.  Complete.
    if (current == controllers.length-1) 
      return controllers[current](req, res, next);

    // We're in the middle somewhere.  Wrap in core.stack().
    current++;
    function wrap() {
      console.log('--> Current in wrapper:'+current);
      return core.stack(req, res, controllers, current)
    }
    return controllers[current](req, res, wrap);
  }
```

Output:

```
--> Current in stack:0
TypeError: Property '1' of object function (req, res, next) {
    if (true) {
      console.log("checking.  Success!");
      // process the next action in the route
      next();
    } else {
      // on failure, flash a message.  
      console.log('Huh.  That didn\'t work.  Login and click the resend verification email link');
    }
  },, is not a function
    at Object.core.stack (/home/michael/scm/mean-core/core.js:47:32)
    at Object.handle (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/app/routes/users.server.routes.js:24:13)
    at next_layer (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at c (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24)
    at param (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:14)
    at param (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:282:16)
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:298:3)
    at next (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
    at next (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
GET /auth/confirm/adsfasdfasdf 500 61ms
--> Current in stack:0
TypeError: Property '1' of object function (req, res, next) {
    if (true) {
      console.log("checking.  Success!");
      // process the next action in the route
      next();
    } else {
      // on failure, flash a message.  
      console.log('Huh.  That didn\'t work.  Login and click the resend verification email link');
    }
  },, is not a function
    at Object.core.stack (/home/michael/scm/mean-core/core.js:47:32)
    at Object.handle (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/app/routes/users.server.routes.js:24:13)
    at next_layer (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at c (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24)
    at param (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:14)
    at param (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:282:16)
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:298:3)
    at next (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
    at next (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
--> Current in stack:0
TypeError: Property '1' of object function (req, res, next) {
    if (true) {
      console.log("checking.  Success!");
      // process the next action in the route
      next();
    } else {
      // on failure, flash a message.  
      console.log('Huh.  That didn\'t work.  Login and click the resend verification email link');
    }
  },, is not a function
    at Object.core.stack (/home/michael/scm/mean-core/core.js:47:32)
    at Object.handle (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/app/routes/users.server.routes.js:24:13)
    at next_layer (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at c (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24)
    at param (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:14)
    at param (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:282:16)
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:298:3)
    at next (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
    at next (/home/michael/scm/writermustwrite.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the error, you could debug (https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) and see what's happening inside the controller functions.

For the logic, i think you are missing the first controller invocation as current++ is before controllers[current] and so you would never invoke the first controller.

For the solution, you could add multiple route handlers for the same path. `next` variable points to the next handler for the same route. so, you would achieve the same thing with much simplified code.

```
app.route('/auth/confirm/:confirmationCode')
         .get(app.core.users.checkEmailVerification)
         .get(app.core.users.processVerification)
         .get(app.mean.subscribeMarketingEmails);
```

or even this

```
app.route('/auth/confirm/:confirmationCode').get(
                  app.core.users.checkEmailVerification,
                  app.core.users.processVerification,
                  app.mean.subscribeMarketingEmails);
```

the controller functions will be passed req, res and next objects.

Comment: Waaaaaaaaay easier.  Thanks!