# Can I have one express route, but multiple controllers depending on query

Tags: express, routes, router

Let's say I have this route

```
app.route('/upload').post(???);
```

Is there a way to route to different controllers based on a query string for exemple?

I know I could just use different endpoints, or I could have a "main" controller that acts as a relay with a switch case to the right controller but is there any other way?

Exemple `req.query.type === "x"` then controller x is called, but if 
`req.query.type === "y"` then controller y is called.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23718541/2829540 ?

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff If I understand correctly, that answer is calling multiple controllers one after the other, as for me, it's really calling one from many choices depending on the query string

Comment: I think you're just designing things wrong.  The query parameters should be parameters to a given controller.  The path (e.g. route) should determine which controller gets called.  You can always hack anything (like just have a little code in the route handler that decides which controller to call based on the query parameters, but I think you should just fix the URL design rather than hack it.  Like maybe you need `/upload/x` and `/upload/y` rather than put the type in the query string.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes i'm inclined to agree with you, I was mainly curious :)

Answer (score 0):

This is basically how I do it, but I am eager to see better implementations:

```
// routes.js

 router
      .route('/upload')
      .get(MyController.getUploads);


// MyController.js
export default class MyController {
  static getUploads(req, res) {
if (req.params.id) {
      UploadDao
        .getSingle(req.params.id)
        .then(upload => res.status(200).json(upload))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).json(error));
    } else if (req.query.search) {
      UploadDao
        .getFilteredList(req.query.search)
        .then(uploads => res.status(200).json(uploads))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).json(error));
    } else {
      UploadDao
        .getAll()
        .then(figures => res.status(200).json(figures))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).json(error));
    }
}
```

I guess a switch would be better to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider we want to switch between two controller say controller1 and controller2 based on query `shouldRunFirstController`. we can achieve same in this way for same path.

We will be switching between them as follows:

```
router.get('/', , (req, res, next) =>
  req.query.shouldRunFirstController
    ? controller1(req, res, next)
    : controller(req, res, next)
);
```